# C++ array of the same class hierarchy

Tags: c++, arrays, class

According to my book, if I want to make an array of objects that are not in the same class but in the same class hierarchy, I need to use pointers:

```
class text
{
public:
    void write(string text);
    void show();
private:
    string texte;
};

void text::write(string text)
{
    texte = text;
}

void text::show()
{
    cout << texte;
}


class text_with_stars : public text
{
public:
    void show();
};

void text_with_stars::show()
{
    cout << "*";
    text::show();
    cout << "*";
}

int main()
{
    text* array[2];
    array[0] = new text;
    array[0]->write("Hello");
    text_with_stars* pointer = new text_with_stars;
    pointer->write("Hi");
    array[1] = pointer;
    for (int i=0;i<2;i++)
    {
        array[i]->show();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But when I do this, the output is "HelloHi" meaning that the second object used the show version that is from text and not from text_with_stars, but I made it exactly the same way that the book described. What Is the problem??

Here is what is written in the book:

> ```
>  Question* quiz[2];
>  quiz[0] = new Question;
>  quiz[0]->set_text("Who was the inventor of C++?");
>  quiz[0]->set_answer("Bjarne Stroustrup");
>  ChoiceQuestion* cq_pointer = new ChoiceQuestion;
>  cq_pointer->set_text("In which country was the inventor of C++ born?")
>  cq_pointer->add_choice("Australia",false);
>  ...
>  quiz[1] = cq_pointer;
> ```

The chapter  right next to the one I was reading is about virtual functions and it explains that the system will always use the member functions of Question instead of ChoiceQuestion, looks like I should read more before asking questions on internet!

Comment: C++ for everyone, I edited my answer to show what the book contains.

Comment: Full title, author, edition and page number please.

Comment: C++ for everyone, Cay Horstmann, second edition, page 457 but it's pointless because there is no error, I just didn't read the next section before asking my question

Answer (score 3):

```
void show()
```

needs to be virtual in the base class if you want to use methods from derived classes from base class pointers

Comment: right! that is it should be written as: virtual void show() in the base class

Comment: I don' know for now what is "virtual" but the text in my book  is: Question* quiz[2]; quiz[0] = new question; ...; ChoiceQuestion* cq_pointer = new ChoiceQuestion; ...; quiz[1] = cq_pointer;     Is this an  error?

Comment: This is completely valid code. But if you store a pointer of a derived class in a variable that is declared as a pointer of the base class, you will call the methods of the base class. Even though the memory of the derived class is allocated. Until you cast the pointer to the derived class again.

Comment: I would be so heartened if you understood why such-and-such cannot be done rather than citing "because the book says."

Comment: I'm sorry if that was what I sounded like, I thought the book was wrong so that was my reaction. As for my understanding of the problem, I can say that two answers helped me to grasp what these virtual functions are and the next section in my book is about virtual functions too.

Answer (score 1):

The reason this is happening is because the function you are calling is *non-virtual*.

Let's say we have a `class Parent` and a `class Child` inheriting from the parent:

```
class Parent {
public:
    void f() {
        cout << "Parent::f()" << endl;
    }
};

class Child : public Parent {
public:
    void f() {
        cout << "Child::f()" << endl;
    }
};
```

Now, let's make a pointer to a `Parent` and store a `Child` in it (polymorphism):

```
Parent *ptr = new Child;
ptr->f();
```

At this point, the compiler sees `ptr` having type `Parent*` and determines that the function to be called is Parent::f().

In order to call `Child::f()` when dealing with polymorphism? The `Parent::f()` must be defined `virtual`. The compiler then generates code to check at run-time the value that is stored in memory to call the appropriate (child) function.

In short: *ONLY when a function is virtual and is called on a pointer or reference, a memory lookup is made to determine the **actual type** at that point in memory. Otherwise it is not.*